# Nativescript - FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process

Tags: android, firebase, nativescript

I´m really desperate about this problem. I´m trying to solve this issue for such a long time now, but I just can´t get it working.

My goal is to use Firebase withhin my Nativescript-App, which also uses Angular 7, but every time I try to "begin" using firebase, I get the following error:

```
Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.nativescript. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

I already tried that. I followed this tutorial:https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase

My Nativescript App is build in "Typescript", so I choose the Typescript-way.

Since I don´t have the **app.js**, I started the .init in **app.ts** like so:

```
import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application";
import * as FirebaseApp from "nativescript-plugin-firebase/app"
import { environment } from './environments/environment';


 FirebaseApp.initializeApp(environment.firebase);

 import * as firebase from "nativescript-plugin-firebase";

 firebase.init({
    // Optionally pass in properties for database, authentication and cloud messaging,
    // see their respective docs.
  }).then(
    () => {
      console.log("firebase.init done");
    },
    error => {
      console.log(`firebase.init error: ${error}`);
    }
  );

application.run({ moduleName: "app-root" });
```

When I try `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(environment.firebase)`, it crashes and says in the log:

```
S: firebase.init error: Firebase already initialized
Successfully synced application com.nativescript. on device 97412f42.
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nativescript./com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.nativescript.. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
System.err:
...
```

That´s interesting, because above it says "already initialized", but right after that it says "FirebaseApp is not initialized". Okay, so I decide to remove `firebase.init({...})` because maybe that´s just too much init, but obviously nope:

```
System.err: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nativescript./com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.nativescript. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
System.err:
...
```

Don´t worry, I purposly removed com.native.script.THEID, just in case.

When I decide to replace `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(environment.firebase)` with the `firebase.init-part` it also gives the same error.

My **environment.ts** is in a folder called **environment** and it´s in the same directory as **app.ts** (the folder).

This is how **environment.ts** is looking like:

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    firebase: {
      apiKey: 'THE API KEY',
      authDomain: 'THE AUTH DOMAIN',
      databaseURL: 'THE DATABASE URL',
      projectId: 'THE PROJECT ID',
      storageBucket: 'THE STORAGE BUCKET',
      messagingSenderId: 'THE SENDER ID'
    },
  };
```

I already download the **google-services.json** from Firebase Console (where you setup your App) and pasted it into **app/App_Resources/Android/**

Please guys, I really don´t know any further. I even tried the second page of Google Search.
If you need any infos, please let me know.

Comment: Why you have two initialise calls? initializeApp is simply an alias of init, you just have to use the one you are comfortable with.

Comment: Hello @Manoj and thanks for your comment!
As I stated in the post, I already tried one of them alone, but it still didn´t work.
I fixed it by creating a new project with angular-templates, unfortunately I must have messed something really bad up when I activated multiDex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MY SOLUTION**
Unfortunately I had to abandon this project and create a new one with angular-templates.
I must have messed something up while enabling mutliDex since I had struggles enabling it back then.

My theory is that, by messing up the activation of multiDex, I probably create two instances of my app build when I run `tns run android`.

So, the only solution was to start over again, but at least the Firebase initialization works now just fine!